# How to Submit Multiple Forms To a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Below is the example form , which is generated through looping in php and wants to submit form data one by one form, from which all form data will be inserted in database correctly via single `get.php` file and also wants to get redirected to form action file after submitting the form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="get.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="track_id" class="control-label col-sm-2">track_id :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="track_id" value="3407" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="seokey" class="control-label col-sm-2">seokey :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="seokey" value="Aahun Aahun Aahun Aahun - Jai Jawan Jai Kisaan" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="track_title" class="control-label col-sm-2">track_title :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="tracktitle" value="Aahun Aahun Aahun Aahun - Jai Jawan Jai Kisaan" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="meta_track" class="control-label col-sm-2">meta_track :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="metatrack" value="Aahun Aahun Aahun Aahun - Jai Jawan Jai Kisaan.mp3" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="get.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="track_id" class="control-label col-sm-2">track_id :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="track_id" value="3407" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="seokey" class="control-label col-sm-2">seokey :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="seokey" value="Aahun Aahun Aahun Aahun - Jai Jawan Jai Kisaan" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="track_title" class="control-label col-sm-2">track_title :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="tracktitle" value="Aahun Aahun Aahun Aahun - Jai Jawan Jai Kisaan" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="meta_track" class="control-label col-sm-2">meta_track :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="metatrack" value="Aahun Aahun Aahun Aahun - Jai Jawan Jai Kisaan.mp3" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</form><form class="form-horizontal" action="get.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="track_id" class="control-label col-sm-2">track_id :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="track_id" value="3407" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="seokey" class="control-label col-sm-2">seokey :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="seokey" value="Aahun Aahun Aahun Aahun - Jai Jawan Jai Kisaan" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="track_title" class="control-label col-sm-2">track_title :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="tracktitle" value="Aahun Aahun Aahun Aahun - Jai Jawan Jai Kisaan" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="meta_track" class="control-label col-sm-2">meta_track :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" name="metatrack" value="Aahun Aahun Aahun Aahun - Jai Jawan Jai Kisaan.mp3" id="track_id" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10" style="margin-top:10px;">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

I have tried much more to doing it myself but failed. `jquery` or `Ajax` is fine.

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend that you google for "How to use forms" - Your submit button isn't inside a form, you can't submit multiple forms at the same time without AJAX. - And if you have tried with AJAX; include it in your question.

Comment: The first place to start is to add a NAME tag to your form.  Without that, there is no way to tell which form you are submitting.

Comment: @durbnpoisn can you give a more specific example like the above form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. It will submit each form via ajax when the button is clicked. The last form will be submitted normally so the redirect will occur.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var $forms = $('form');
    var numForms = $forms.length;
    $forms.each(function(i, el){
        if(i < numForms - 1){
           $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize());
        }else{
           $(this).submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Form data can be accessed via the `$_POST` superglobal with the `name` attribute of the form element for e.g `$_POST['tracktitle']`

Comment: how can i get the submitted data of each form in `get.php` and process them.

Comment: o.k.. i am just trying out !!

Comment: Hi..Via this method only single form is being submitted. and that form is last form

Comment: Are you positive you haven't missed the ajax submits?

Comment: No I have't missed. the submits.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ysc0bkg2/ All of the forms are being submitted. They are submitted in 3 separate requests